# batch Copy and replace files from server to my documents-Windows 7 (or xp)

Tags: batch-file, copy

I need to automate a batch script to copy project data from the server and replace into a project folder on each of the 30+ users's "My Documents" folder.
The users will be in a network, and I want the batch file to automatically run at login.

How do I modify my code from:

```
@echo off
COPY \\servername\Project\Data\*.* C:\TEMP\"FileCopy Test"\*.*
Echo Done.
pause
```

To copy into every user's My Documents directory?  My attempt below failed:

```
@echo off
COPY \\servername\Project\Data\*.* C:\Documents and Settings\user.name\My Documents\FileCopy Test\*.*
Echo Done.
pause
```

Please help:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Enviroment variables of Windows:

```
@echo off
COPY \\servername\Project\Data\*.* "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\FileCopy Test\"
Echo Done.
pause
```

PS: And remember to use doublequotes with several space names in folders.